# C# dynamic dll Reference dll call is error

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll

When I call the dynamic reference dll in the program that I made in C #, by calling the method of reference dll in a dynamic reference, I want to process.

But what I do not who can you let me know how Toka point that must be around when you call a reference to a dynamic reference an error?
Give me the source reference under please:

> Error 
>         2015-07-06 13: 49: 05,711 ERROR: Error in the Agent: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Throw an exception has
>   been the target of an invocation. ---> System.BadImageFormatException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'inDllTest, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture
>   = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' or one of the files could not be loaded or assemblies that are dependent on this. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: coding this is<--Dynamic Dll-->
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using SIERP001.Common;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SIERP001.Models;
using inDllTest; //<--Reference dll

public string InOutCall(){
  reutrn IndllTest.dddd(json);//<--Reference dll Method call Err
}

Comment: I think it's 32-bit / 64-bit confliction. Might be your project set to 32 bit and while the class its referencing is set to 64-bit.

Comment: Two of the dll was built in the Any Cpu.
 However, the same error occurs.

Comment: You have 32bit dll\exe in your project?

Comment: The two projects that I made right.

Comment: Dynamic error occurs in the call reference to the reference.